# Can't create service using Spring and JavaConfig

Tags: java, spring

I Can't create service using Spring and JavaConfig.

Here is my main class:

```
public class MainApp
{

    private static final Logger LOGGER = getLogger(MainApp.class);


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(HelloWorldConfig.class);
        MessageService mService  = context.getBean(MessageService.class);

        HelloWorld helloWorld = context.getBean(HelloWorld.class);


        LOGGER.debug("Message from HelloWorld Bean: " + helloWorld.getMessage());

        Message message = new Message();
        message.setMessage(helloWorld.getMessage());
        mService.SaveMessage(message);



        helloWorld.setMessage("I am in Staten Island, New York");


        LOGGER.debug("Message from HelloWorld Bean: " + helloWorld.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Here is my config

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.xxxx.HelloSpringJavaBasedJavaConfig"})
@Import(DatabaseConfig.class)
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class HelloWorldConfig
{

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean
    public MessageService messageService() {
        return new MessageServiceImpl();
    }


    @Bean
    public HelloWorld getHelloWorld()
    {
        HelloWorld hw = new HelloWorld();

       /*
        This is use to read in the property from the application.properties file
       */

        hw.setMessage(env.getProperty("bean.text"));

        return hw;
    }


}
```

here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.xxxx.HelloSpringJavaBasedJavaConfig.service.MessageService] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: messageServiceImpl,messageService
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: see the error above I just added it

Comment: @JesseWebb I added the error about

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the first bean works

Comment: @SJS Show the class definition for `MessageServiceImpl`. It should not have the `@Component` annotation, because Spring will create a bean for it automatically.

Comment: did you annotate the class MessageService with @Component or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I bet you've annotated `MessageServiceImpl` with `@Service` or similar. Combined with classpath scanning, that means two MessageServiceImpl beans are being created, once by the scanning, and once from the `messageService` method. Get rid of one or the other.

Comment: thanks for all your help.. maybe you can tell me why my database is not working